# ubuntu 18.04 intel graphic 9b41 unclaimed, external hdmi display doesn't work

Tags: graphics, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-18.04

I got an HP laptop envy x360 core i7 10th gen. 
I installed and upgraded ubuntu 18.04 on it (latest).
I installed lightdm and mate (but I guess this is not relevant in the problem)

The builtin display, though 'working' seems not 'claimed', as reported by lshw, dunno if this is a problem.

My real problem is that plugin an external hdmi display (samsung 4k) do nothing, dmesg shows no kenel activity, no plugin plugout is detected.

I have another 'older' hp envy x360 with core i7 8th gen, and this one works properly, allowing comparison if needed.

The older envy360 lspci shows

```
    VY$  lspci -k | grep  VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 21)
```

The faulting newer x360 shows

```
PW$  lspci -k | grep  VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b41 (rev 02)
```

So it sounds like the intel graphic interface differ, and I don't know how to handle this.

The lshw excerp for the older (good) x360 shows

```
*-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: UHD Graphics 620
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 07
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:148 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

and the faulty one

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 02
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I wonder if I need to load some intel drivers for this newer envy x360.

Thanx in advance for any pointers.

Comment: the problem of UNCLAIMED display is well known, especially for those who have latest AMD graphics. Even this case is with INTEL, the principal cure is the same as for AMDs.
Please find detailed step-by-step how-to for Ryzen with code-named 'Renoir' graphics [here]. [here]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297325/new-radeon-graphics-with-ubuntu/1320189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Face not so red :)

Well I got a 'working' config after re-installing latest 18.04 Ubuntu, BUT, it was pure luck, after a couple a reboot I lost the external 4K HDMI display.

BTW the display is a SAMSUMG4K UHD curve with 3840x2160 def.

Basically what happen is that randomly plugin this display into the HP envy x3600 was working or not.

Not working mean the display showing 'HDMI' (as a source, there is also an DP source possible), then was flickering black/dark grey, never displaying my desktop, the internal display also going a bit crazy.

I suspected all sort of HW problem, I crossed out the SAMSUNG display along with its HDMI cable, as plugin this as is in a second DESKTOP was always working, so display + cable ok.

The the HP envy external HDMI connector is kinda at fault, or the Ubuntu driver.

And finally I got a workaroud, a little all-in-one USB type C hub, with a lan, 3 USB3, sd card reader AND HDMI 4K connector (in the magnitude of $30)

I hooked this hub (kinda docking), and plugged the HDMI cable in the hub instead in the HP connector and bingo, the external display always shows up correctly, we can as well plug and play the HDMI cable, X11 always reliably fallback in the mono display mode, with primary display reassigned correctly, then replug trig a correct dual display.

Now lshw shows

```
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:146 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Now all is back to norm, why the hp envy/ubuntu is not able to handle the external display stay a mistery, but I can travel with the little usb hub as an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Red face on :(

Well the 18.04 .iso I installed 'may be' was not the pure latest, so despite the update/upgrade, the newer machine graphic was not Ok.

I then download the very latest 18.04 .iso and there, from the .iso usb stick, even before install the dual display did work, and so did it after install, I then installed MATE, which chocked a bit, but after a couple of resolution adjust of the external display finally end up to work.

So I guess the answer is, do install the very latest ubuntu on the very latest HW :(

Cheers.

Comment: Good you figured out. I have just checked kernel sources and ID is there.